# JS wrapper objects strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, v8, gecko

Can someone explain the behaviour below, it is about the temporary wrapper objects in JS, but when I try to use them on number literal they fail. Am I mistaken or this changed recently, I tried on V8 and Gecko, same story.

```
    'stringWrapper'.charAt(0);
    "s"
    1.toString();
    VM8363:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL(…)InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM8253:875InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM8253:808InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM8253:664
    typeof 1
    "number"
    (1+0).toString();
    "1"
    typeof (1+0)
    "number"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting "feature" in JavaScript and other dynamically typed languages, like Python, where you can call methods or access properties on an integer.

What's actually happening is that the engine sees, or lexes, the `1.toString()` as a floating point number where the `toString()` part is where the first decimal should be.

The solution is either to double-dot it, `1..toString()` and omit the trailing decimal or wrap the number within parenthesis `(1).toString()` to evaluate the number and then call `toString` on the result.

Comment: heh this interesting, yep maybe i saw this working with no problems in python not JS :). double dot also works :) thanks

Comment: It will not work in Python. Try evaluating `1.real` in Python. You will get a syntax error and either double-dot or wrap in parenthesis but alas it'll work fine in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

More interesting JavaScript things: `1 .toString()` is valid! `1. toString()` is not.

You may enjoy [Kyle Simpson's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pL28CcEijU) on weird JavaScript quirks